# Help to choose Alfresco or Nuxeo for DMS

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, document-management, dms, ecm

I have requirement to develop DMS(Document Managemen System)  with some initial requirements:

1. If possible DMS should be open source
2. Initially DMS should support up to 500 users
3. System should be scalable in sence od users or content
4. Docuemtns/Content should be stored on a file system
5. Document should be able to be  marked for later destruction
6. Mandatory  to have workflow capabilities
7. Mandatory  to have version control capability
8. Nice to have SSO(Single Sign On) with Liferay portal
9. Nice to have posibility to expose some of funccionality via portlets in Liferay
10. Document management should be done via the web interface
11. Nice to have shared drive capability
12. Nice to have events and notifications about add/change content

At the moment I am in doubth to choose between Alfresco and Nuxeo.

I will appreciate any help to choose between them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not much experience with Nuxeo, but here is for Alfresco:

> 1.If possible DMS should be open source

Yes.

> 2.Initially DMS should support up to 500 users

Yes, if you have a good server.

> 3.System should be scalable in sence od users or content

Yes.

> 4.Docuemtns/Content should be stored on a file system

Yes. Only metadata is stored in a database.

> 5.Document should be able to be marked for later destruction

The free Records Management module has retention capabilities.

> 6.Mandatory to have workflow capabilities

Yes.

> 7.Mandatory to have version control capability

Yes.

> 8.Nice to have SSO(Single Sign On) with Liferay portal

Yes.

> 9.Nice to have posibility to expose some of funccionality via portlets in Liferay

Alfresco and Liferay work very well together.

> 10.Document management should be done via the web interface

Yes.

> 11.Nice to have shared drive capability

Yes.

> 12.Nice to have events and notifications about add/change content

Not sure about this one. The Share module has this feature, but not sure about the main DM application.

Comment: Item 12 can be done in the main DM application with a content rule.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the Nuxeo system, but we are using Alfresco as a document storage and session server. We have our own GUI and only use it as a back-end system. So far we had no problems. Plus Alfresco has a nice REST interface which makes it easy to integrate into any existing system.